# WCF ASP.NET Membership provider - need verifyuser function?

Tags: wcf

I've been following this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx for using WCF and ASP.NET MEmbership provider.

However I can't see any function similar to this VerifyUserNamePassword(username,password).

Do I need to create this function or provider will handle this behind the scene? Any good example will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provider will do everything for you. You just have to correctly configure your service as described in referenced article.

Comment: Thanks v. much @Ladislav Mrnka